# dnSpy - What do these symbols mean?

Tags: decompilation, dll, .net

When decompiling a dll file there are certain lines of code that read like this:

`return \u0013.\u0002.\u0001(url, info);`

I have two questions on this:

1) does `\u00xx` mean that it is obfuscated, if yes, what steps can I take to understand it

2)  what are the `.` between each one, is it a dnSpy thing or does it mean something in C#

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These are [Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) characters that are not supported by the font used by dnSpy.
Usually, you'll see it when the code is obfuscated or in cases where the developer used languages as Chinese and Russian in their code. But yeah, usually obfuscation.

You can try to deobfuscate this .Net binary by using [de4dot](https://github.com/0xd4d/de4dot) which is doing an incredible job with deobfuscating obfuscated .net applications. de4dot's engine was later used to create [dnSpy](https://github.com/0xd4d/dnSpy) which is my favorite .Net decompiler.

The separating dots are the [dot Operator](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operator), just as in most popular programming languages, the dot operator is used to access members of variables, types, etc. "Members" can be a method, attribute, and others.

In your case, `\u0001` is a method of `\u0002` which is a member of the variable `\u0013`.

Comment: Can de4dot deobfuscated any .NET executable?

Comment: No. But it'll try and usually will output a bit less-obfuscated binary. There are indeed obfuscators that will beat de4dot